# How do I center Subscribe Form

Tags: css

How Can I center the subscribe form of this webpage: http://www.dianerosesolomon.com/affiliate-order/

I've tried to add

```
<div class="AW-Form-1862283401" style="width:100%;display: block;margin:0 auto;text-align: center;">
</div>
```

but it is not working.

Comment: You should consider moving your CSS-styling to an external file.

Comment: it is a third party subscribe form. & I'm already using this form to another page with left align. Negative reputation is not going to help me, I need solution.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a third party subscribe-form, you can still target it from your CSS-file.

Comment: It also doesn't matter you use it on another page with left-align, you apparently have access to the HTML of the form, so you could just give it a unique class or div so you can target this specific one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change width to 44%

```
<div id="af-body-1862283401" class="af-body af-standards" style="width: 44%;">
```

this will help you to keep your design responsive. Tested on Chrome

Comment: This doesn't work on all browsers. On firefox - button submit is below Name and Email.

Comment: @repincln : refer this for multi browser support : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9782135/1982680

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `width`

```
#af-form-1862283401, #af-form-1862283401 .quirksMode {
    max-width: 436px;
    width: 40%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to form element:

```
form.af-form-wrapper{
   margin-left: auto; 
   margin-right: auto; 
   display: inline-block;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.AW-Form-1862283401 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```